# Is it possible to load a wasm runtime separately from the binary that requires it?

Tags: webassembly

Say I have a web application written in Go that compiles to web assembly.

Is it possible for developers to ship the runtime separately from the main application code where separate binaries containing the application code use/share the runtime?

e.g.

First we load
`https://myserver.com/go-wasm-1-13.wasm`

Then we load `https://myserver.com/app-1.wasm`

`app-1.wasm` uses the runtime to execute itself

Later we may load `app-2.wasm` which would share the same `go-wasm-1-13.wasm`

Following binaries on different pages could take advantage of the runtime (`go-wasm-1-13.wasm`) being cached

Answer (score 1):

WebAssembly supports [dynamic linking](https://webassembly.org/docs/dynamic-linking/).  So it's possible only if one can compile the Go runtime as a shared library.